# Wordpress Gutenberg : What is the "Block Name" setting in the inspector

Tags: wordpress, attributes, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Does anyone know the purpose of the "Block Name" parameter in the Gutenberg Inspector? I don't understand what it's for, it's not saved in the database and I can't find any documentation about it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is used in Document Overview panel. To make it easier to navigate complex materials.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks ! However, how to use it in my own custom block.I can't find any doc in https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/